# Android: Reduce space between 2 textviews in a TableRow

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to reduce the space between 2 `textfields` in a `TableRow`. My goal is that the text "`20$`" can goes to the left in order to stay alignment with the title "Ultimos meses", but I can't move it.

[image]

The code I have is:

```
<TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textMesPassado2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="Janeiro"
                android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                android:textColor="@color/brown1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textValorPassada2"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:text="20$"
                android:textColor="@color/brown1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </TableRow>
```

Can you please help?

Comment: `android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"` this line is adding all the space between `Janeiro` and `20$`. If you want to remove some space, either remove the line or make it less than 50

Comment: @Napster if I remove it, it will appear "Janeiro20$" and it will not be centered...

Comment: I don't think there is an XML way of doing what you want (aligning the content of a table row to the content of something else of which we don't even know what it is - another table row, a text view, ...). It can be done programmatically, by measuring the right side of the header thing and setting the right side of the text view in the table row to the same value. Is this really what you need?